# How to check the stdout of a command in a Bash while conditionality check?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to check for the output of a command as a breakout condition for while loop in Bash, but it keeps skipping past the block, even while the last echo confirms the value as `"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"`.

This is what I have:

```
stackname=cf_test
while [[ $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus') == "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]; do
  echo -e "   $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus'): waiting for current stack to delete before re-deploying..."
  sleep 30
done

echo -e $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus')
```

What should I change?

edit:

Adding `-x` debug flag, gives:

```
▶ bash -x ~/Downloads/test_script.sh
+ stackname=cf_test
++ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name cf_test
++ jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus'
+ [[ "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS" == \D\E\L\E\T\E\_\I\N\_\P\R\O\G\R\E\S\S ]]
++ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name cf_test
++ jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus'
+ echo -e '"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"'
"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"
```

Comment: Please run the script with `bash -x yourscript` and post the resulting debug log

Comment: @thatotherguy Added the debug log

Comment: You have added a single line of debug log output. This means that it's not possible to see what the script does next or why it does so. Please make sure that you run exactly and only the code you have posted, and include the complete, unabbreviated debug log.

Comment: @thatotherguy Pasted the full log. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This seemed to finally work: `while [ $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .                                StackStatus')=DELETE_IN_PROGRESS ]; do`. I will leave this as a comment, hoping someone posts a better explanation as answer.

Comment: (contd)... spoke too soon. My comment above does not work either. Now, the condition is always true, even when the command returns `DELETE_FAILED`

Comment: But this definitively fixed (note the single quotes surrounding double quoted string value): `while [[ $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus') == '"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"' ]]; do`. The reason seems to be that the double quotes is part of the string value returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debug log shows the problem (even though the `[[` line itself weirdly obscures it):

```
+ echo -e '"DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"'
```

The value you are comparing contains literal double quotes. That's why the match fails. Your right-hand side of `==` contains syntactical double quotes that are not treated as part of the string.

To fix it, use `jq -r` to output the string without JSON formatting and escaping:

```
json='{ "foo": "bar" }'
jq '.foo' <<< "$json"     # Shows bad 5 character value: "bar"
jq -r '.foo' <<< "$json"  # Shows good 3 character value: bar
```

In your case:

```
while [[ $(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname} | jq -r '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus') == "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]; doq -r '.Stacks | .[0] | .StackStatus') == "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS" ]]; do
  echo "Still deleting"
  sleep 30
done
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would move the comparison inside `jq`. By default, `jq` will succeed, regardless of the logical status of the comparison you make.

```
% jq -n '3 == 3'; echo $?
true
0
% jq -n '3 != 3'; echo $?
false
0
```

To change this, use the `-e` option.

```
% jq -en '3 == 3'; echo $?
true
0
% jq -en '3 != 3'; echo $?
false
1
```

Doing this eliminates the need for the `[[ ... ]]` command.

```
while x=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname});
      jq -ne --arg x "$x" '$x.Stacks.[0].StackStatus == "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"'; do
  printf '%s: waiting for current stack to delete before re-deploying...\n' "$x"
  sleep 30
done

printf '%s\n' "$x"
```

Comment: I don't have `jq` to hand but your words imply the 2nd `jq` command in your answer will return `true` not `false` as shown.

Comment: Thank, that fixed it. Although that exact expression failed for me, I had to tweak it just a bit: `x=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stackname});
      echo $x | jq -e '.Stacks| .[0] | .StackStatus | contains("DELETE_IN_PROGRESS")'`

Comment: I have few other while and until loops that need to check for the stdout of commands (that dont involve jq). Is there a generic solution for all such cases?